# iOS4 cannot detect left right swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios4, mobile-safari

I am producing a mobile website (safari mobile not uiwebview), with jQuery and the viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, user-scalable=0, initial-scale=default" id="viewport">
```

I have swipe detection working via the jQuery touchSwipe plugin http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/

```
$(window).swipe({
    swipeLeft  :function(){ console.log('1'); arrows.eq(1).click(); },
    swipeRight :function(){ console.log('0'); arrows.eq(0).click(); },
    allowPageScroll:"vertical"
});
```

Swipe detects fine on iPad iOS5 and Android but iPhone iOS4 nothing triggers. I did some debugging

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){
     console.log(e.touches[0].clientX+' | '+e.touches[0].clientY);
};
```

tried out all the basics clientX pageX ect. all seems to work fine and return valid data. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I also tried http://jgestures.codeplex.com/documentation with oddly enough the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. This issue was very simple:

```
$(window)
```

does not receive touch events in iOS4 while it does in iOS5 and Android. While

```
$(document)
```

DOES receive touch events on all devices. Go figure.